# How to pre-define/generate a unique ID in sails.js?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

I'm using sails.js and mySQL db to build a website. For solving [this particular problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255872/jquery-file-upload-send-all-files-in-one-post), I have thought of pre-defining my ID attribute of my model(taking care of uniqueness by using the timestamp). So once I create a record with the ID that I've defined, I will be able to associate the files(which I upload using JQuery file upload plugin) with this particular record that I created. But I am not sure how to do this in sails.js. Is this possible?

Or can I just define a separate attribute which will have the property `unique: true` and generate it on front end and pass it over to backend and use this attribute to associate my files.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then yes, you can define your own primary key to be used instead of an automatically generated ID.

```
myAwesomeId: {
    type: 'string',
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    primaryKey: true
},
// other attributes
```

Comment: **unique** property will *not* work with *primaryKey: true*